# rendre un service vs faire une faveur

Tags: expressions, synonymes

Y a-t-il une différence entre les expressions "rendre un service" et "faire une faveur" (= to do a favor) ?

"rendre une faveur" signifie-t-il "to return a favor"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les mots « faveur » et « service » n'ont pas tout à fait le même sens. Dans « faveur » il y a une idée de bienveillance qu'on a envers quelqu'un.  Une faveur c'est quelque chose que l'on fait pour être agréable à quelqu'un, ça peut être fait sans qu'on nous le demande.

Exemple de situation où je pourrais l'employer : on fait la queue pour avoir des places pour un concert de Sting, j'arrive au guichet et on me dit que j'ai de la chance, je vais avoir la dernière place. Derrière moi il y a une vieux monsieur dont c'est peut-être la dernière occasion de sa vie de voir Sting en concert, je le laisse passer devant moi, on peut dire que je lui « fais une faveur ».

Dans « service », il y a bien sûr aussi l'idée qu'on veut faire plaisir, mais en plus il y a une idée d'utilité qu'il n'y a pas dans « faveur ». Par exemple je peux dire que j'ai « rendu service » à mon voisin en lui faisant ses courses quand il était malade. Je ne dirais pas dans ce dernier exemple que je lui ai « fait une faveur ».

Je n'ai jamais entendu « rendre une faveur ». On fait/on accorde une faveur et on rend un service. Les emplois trouvés de « rendre une faveur » sont considérés comme des anglicismes.

---

Attention à l'emploi de l'expression *accorder **ses** faveur**s*** (pluriel + déterminant possessif).
 Au sens classique cette expression voulait dire qu'on s'offrait sexuellement à quelqu'un. Elle est moins employée dans ce sens de nos jours et sert surtout au sens figuré pour dire qu'on privilégie/qu'on préfère quelque chose.

Comment: Si ma femme est malade et je cuisine pour elle sans qu'elle me demande, est-ce un service ou une faveur? Selon tus définitions, je pourrais utiliser les deux.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista hehe!!! Ça dépend de comment tu vis les relations avec ta femme ! Moi je dirais ni l'un ni l'autre car il est normal qu'un mari fasse la cuisine avec sa femme de façon habituelle et pas seulement les jours où elle est malade. À la rigueur je dirais que tu rends service à la famille, mais pas spécialement à ta femme.

Comment: J'ai assumé une situation où la femme est une femme au foyer et prend soin de toute la cuisine.  Désolé de ne pas avoir été clair.  Et pour que ce soit clair, je suis tout à fait d’accord pour dire que l’homme et la femme devraient partager les tâches ménagères.  C'était juste un (peut-être mauvais) exemple.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Et moi je provoquais un peu...  je dirais que tu rends service (mais pas seulement à ta femme, tu manges aussi, non ?)

Comment: C'est pas grave, un peu de l'humour est toujours le bievenu. Encore une dernière question: Comment pourrais-je dire "to return a favor" si je n'utilise pas "rendre une faveur" ?

Answer (score 0):

**I** « Rendre un service » signifie « faire quelque chose pour quelqu'un, pas nécessairement gratuitement ou sans une rétribution, mais sous aucune obligation, seulement sous la motivation de vouloir aider la personne à qui le service est rendu ».

« Faire une faveur à quelqu'un » signifie « faire profiter quelqu'un de quelque chose gratuitement ».

**II** Oui, « rendre une faveur » signifie  « to return a favour » but just as well « to do a favour » ([reverso](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/rendre+une+faveur)) . On dit aussi « rendre la pareille » pour « rendre une faveur » dans le sens pur de « rendre ».

- Il est « absurde » d’imaginer qu’Israël devra rendre une faveur suite à la reconnaissance de Jérusalem, affirme Netanyahu "C'était une anomalie historique et il était temps que cela … (Web)

C'est pourquoi il vaut mieux dire « faire une faveur » ou (formel) « accorder une faveur » pour « to do a favour ».

Comment: Je ne comprends pas. Comment "service" peut être utilisé avec la motivation d'aider mais sans être nécessairement gratuit? Si quelqu'un fait quelque chose sous la motivation d'aider une personne, cela n'a aucun sens d'accepter une récompense pour cela. Au moins, c'est comme ça en anglais, pour autant que je sache. "a favor"est fait gratuitement, sinon c'est "a service".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista En France il très courant, lorsque quelqu'un vous propose de faire quelque chose qui leur coute en temps et en argent, comme par exemple vous conduire à l'aéroport pour prendre un avion, d'insister pour qu'il/elle soit dédommagé et de lui proposer de l'argent pour son temps et son essence;  parfois les gens accepteront, ce qui est normal si la somme est assez importante, mais pas toujours; quoi qu'il en soit, l'acte consenti par la personne est quand même un service car son temps aurait pu être  passé plus agréablement ou plus utilement; il n'y a aucune idée de profit.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista « Service » en français dans le présent contexte ne signifie pas  « service » en anglais.

Comment: Je comprends maintenant. C'est donc une différence culturelle.  Au Brésil, peu de gens acceptons de l'argent pour des services/faveurs faites à des amis ou à la famille.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Je ne trouve pas la différence si grande, c'est à peu près la même chose en France pour la famille et les amis intimes, sauf, comme je le disais lorsque le service est très important et je crois qu'au Brésil aussi ce devrait être pareil : il y a une limite à tout.